# Update controls based on edit box change in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How can I capture changes in text box value?

I'm researching how to use `OnChange` event function but I don't know how to use it.

```pascal
[Code]
var
  Page: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
    'Personal Information', 'Who are you?',
    'Please specify your name and the company for whom you work, then click Next.');
    
  Page.Add('Server:', False);
  Page.Add('NAME:', False);
  Page.Add('LOCATION:', False);

  Page.Values[0] := ('test0');
  Page.Values[1] := ('test1');
  Page.Values[2] :=  ('string')+Page.Values[0]+('string')+Page.Values[1];
end;
```

I want to alter text of one (2) edit box, as text of other edit boxes (0 and 1) is being changed by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle `OnChange` event like:

```pascal
var
  Page: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure EditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Page.Values[2] := 'string' + Page.Values[0] + 'string' + Page.Values[1];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(...);

  Page.Add('Server:', False);
  Page.Add('NAME:', False);
  Page.Add('LOCATION:', False);

  Page.Values[0] := 'test0';
  Page.Values[1] := 'test1';

  Page.Edits[0].OnChange := @EditChange;
  Page.Edits[1].OnChange := @EditChange;
  // Reflect the initial values
  EditChange(nil);
end;
```

---

Note that the `Edit[2]` can be changed by the user, so maybe you want to set it read only.

```pascal
  Page.Edits[2].ReadOnly := True;
  Page.Edits[2].Color := clBtnFace;
```

[image]

Or you may actually want to use `TLabel` instead.